# Is my code vulnerable to XSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser, xss

I have my website `https://xx.com/guides`

When i scan my website i get this:

> **Issue detail:** The application may be vulnerable to DOM-based cross-site scripting.
>   Data is read from window.location.href and written to $() via the following statement:
>
> ```
>    $('.page-sidebar a[href="' + window.location.href + '"]')
>        .addClass('selected')
> ```

Maybe it's caused by this code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.page-sidebar a[href="' + window.location.href + '"]').addClass('selected')
})
</script>
```

I tried to generate a POC `https://xx.com/guides?"]);alert(2)` but still no luck

1. My browser has disabled XSS filtering
2. I am cetrtain that DOM xss is possible
3. I need help generating POC!

Full code : http://pastebin.com/Bs4vuUH3

Comment: Regardless, it's a good idea to escape `location.href` so that it doesn't break the selector syntax.

Comment: be there is some vulnerability possible like: `href = 'foo"]\');$(\'html\').remove();$(\'.a[href=""';`  but i´m too lazy to get this to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. While you make use of externally inputted data, you never inject it into the DOM.

Comment: WHat you siad i don't understand!

Comment: is my code vulneaurable? if yes, how? or if No then why my scanner is saying yes?

Comment: why does your scanner not answer that

Comment: @AsheshKumar — "No" seems pretty clear. Because your scanner looks for patterns that *might* be XSS risks, it isn't smart enough to make sure they are.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you seem unable to spell "vulnerable" to save your life, here's an answer that's as simple as I can make it.

Is your code vulnerable? **No.**

But it's still not a good idea.

Instead, consider something like this - it's more complex, but much more reliable:

```
$(".page-sidebar a").filter(function() {
    return this.href == window.location.href;
}).addClass("selected");
```

The reason is, let's say I have this link:

```
<a href="/">
```

On this page, that would link to `http://stackoverflow.com/`. But quite clearly, `http://stackoverflow.com/` and `/` are not at all the same. They would not be found by your code. My code, however, uses fully resolved addresses and will work.